# AES key schedule

Tags: c, encryption, cryptography, aes

In tutorials on AES key schedule I saw that the operations of the key schedule(rotate,rcon,s-box) are applied on a 4-byte word.Can you please explain where does this word come from ?I understand i extract it from the key which is 128 bit long.The key is saved as 4x4 matrix.So how can I obtain the word used for the key schedule ?Maybe it is an easy question but I don't understand.Thank you.

Comment: These questions are better asked at crypto.stackexchange.com (if not present there already, of course).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's explained [here (with some code)](http://www.samiam.org/key-schedule.html).  it's the last 4 bytes of the expanded key "so far".

1. you start with 128bit (16 bytes) key.  the first 16 bytes of the expanded key are those bytes.
2. you take the last 4 bytes of that, do the (rotate,rcon,s-box) dance, and get 4 more bytes, which you xor with the 4 bytes 16 bytes earlier (so, first time, at the start of the key), and append that to the expanded key.
3. you take the last 4 bytes of the expanded key (what you just appended), xor it with the bytes 16 bytes "back" (so, first time, bytes 5 to 8), and append the result to the expanded key.
4. you repeat 3 another 2 times, using the last 4 bytes of the expanded key each time.
5. you repeat from 2 until you get the total expanded length you require.

so always, you're using the 4 bytes that were last appended to the expanded key.  and you do it in 16 byte "sections", where the first 4 bytes of the section are "initialised" using (rotate,rcon,s-box).

it's also explained in section 5.2 of [the standard](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/fips197/fips-197.pdf) slightly differently (and in a way that might be clearer in answering your question).  they describe it as always taking the last 4 bytes, and xoring them with the 4 bytes 16 bytes previously PLUS, every 4th time, doing the (rotate,rcon,s-box) dance.  that makes it clearer that the xor in steps 2 and 3 above is "the same".

for longer keys you adjust some of the constants above (so you do longer "sections").